# Shell script invoked through Bamboo is stuck, waiting indefinitely

Tags: linux, bash, sh, bamboo

I was trying to configure Bamboo for our build automation task, which involves executing a ANT project.
but initial environment setup was required, so we have a script name "devsh" for this, which sets up everything also switches to some other directory by default after execution of script.

```
#!/bin/bash
............
..........
..--some 200 line code...
export PATH
export MANPATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export CLASSPATH
export JAVA_HOME
export WORKING_COPY
export BUILD_DIR
export APP_DIR
export ANT_HOME
export ANT_OPTS

# If a shell command was specified then run it, else just exec the shell.
if [ "$EXEC_STRING" ]; then
    eval "exec $EXEC_STRING"
fi

case "$UNAME" in
    CYGWIN*)
# Set a default prompt of: user@host and current_directory
PS1='\[\033]0;\w\007
\033[0;33m\]\u@\h \[\033[1;35m\w\033[0m\]
$ '
export PS1
    ;;
    *)
    ;;
esac

#This is a workaround for config where exported PATH is ignored, and recreated everytime a shell starts - ag
export FORCE_PATH="$PATH"
export FORCE_ANTHOME="$ANT_HOME"

exec $SHELL
```

Now when i try to invoke this script through bamboo, it's waiting for some exit code(i think so because of exec $SHELL statement). although same script is working on local environment. Could someone please help me out here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you put the content of variables EXEC_STRING and SHELL, otherwise to debug add `set -xv` at the beginning of the script (x for debug, v for verbose) (or -xv in the shebang if executed)

Comment: What do you mean by 'working on local environment'?  It looks like it "works" by giving the user a new interactive shell.  If you invoke it through some other process, I would expect that process to wait for the invoked shell to exit.

Comment: What do you hope `exec $SHELL` to accomplish, and why are you surprised if it stops there and waits for your input? The earlier `eval` hacks definitely trigger warnings; see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050